# Customizing service in passwordless plugin in Strapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I am trying to modify the behaviour of the "passwordless" strapi plugin so that it would generate the verification code only with digits. So for this I need to override a function createToken in the plugin's service.

I created a folder with the name of the plugin inside extensions folder as specified in Strapi docs. And inside this folder(strapi-plugin-passwordless) I created a file strapi-server.js in which I export a function:

```
module.exports = (plugin) => {
  plugin.services.passwordless.createToken = async (email, context) => {
    const settings = await this.settings();
    const tokensService = strapi.query("plugin::passwordless.token");
    tokensService.update({ where: { email }, data: { is_active: false } });
    const body = customAlphabet("1234567890", 6);

    const tokenInfo = {
      email,
      body,
      context: JSON.stringify(context),
    };
    return tokensService.create({ data: tokenInfo });
  };

  return plugin;
};
```

The only difference between original createToken function the custom one is that the variable body is in the form of 6 digits.

However, Strapi doesn't run this function, instead it runs the original one on node_modules?
What may I possibly be doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered a similar issue while working with Strapi's Passwordless plugin and needed to customize the service. Here's the solution I found that might be helpful to others facing the same challenge.

The key to understanding this customization lies in recognizing that the service in the Passwordless plugin is not a simple object but a function that returns the service object. This distinction is crucial for properly extending or modifying the service's functionality.

```
export default (plugin: any) => {
  // Get the original passwordlessFactory function
  const passwordlessFactory = plugin.services.passwordless;

  // Override the passwordless service
  plugin.services.passwordless = function (...args: any[]) {
    // Extend the original passwordlessFactory function
    return {
      ...passwordlessFactory(...args),
      async createToken(email: string, context: any) {
        const settings = await this.settings();
        const { token_length = 20, stays_valid = false } = settings;

        await strapi
          .query('plugin::passwordless.token')
          .update({ where: { email }, data: { is_active: false } });

        const body = generateRandomToken(token_length);
        const tokenInfo = {
          email,
          body,
          stays_valid,
          context: JSON.stringify(context),
        };

        return strapi
          .query('plugin::passwordless.token')
          .create({ data: tokenInfo });
      },
    };
  };

  return plugin;
};
```